# Settings for multiple variable resistors in a logic probe

Tags: signal, current-measurement, voltage-measurement

I am building what looks on paper like a really sweet logic probe as a first project.  It includes 3 variable resistors. The site I got the circuit diagram from is translated into english and doesn't make sense.
There is some nonsense about low current measurements.
My question...how do I determine settings for the various resistors?[image]

Also, can I assume VR1 at the top is, by convention, 50K?

Comment: I don't know enough about this circuit to answer, but two spontaneous comments. 1) The pots sets the low and high threshold between 0 and 5 volts. 2) It's unclear to me what purpose the top potentiometer serves, it seems to do more harm than good. Hopefully someone can answer this.

Comment: And who the ... names all potentiometers the same..

Comment: What precise functionality do you want from the LEDs?

Comment: It is a logic probe, right? One led for high, one for low, one for float. I agree, the designer didn't follow naming convention.. I don't know enough to figure out what the VR1? does either. I am fairly junior at this. It would be great if you knowledgeable folks could help me on the straight path to do this correctly. Thanks.